# How to set Group column height in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

Actually I am generating receipt and it looks like this in 2 columns:

```
-------------------------  
| Receipt 1 | Receipt 2 |  // Group Header Section for Receipt-No
|_______________________|
|  Item 1   | Item 1    |  // Group Detail Section
|  Item 2   | Item 2    |
|  Item 3   |------------ 
------------- Receipt2  |
|  Receipt1 | Total     |  // Group Footer Section for Receipt-No
|  Total    |___________| 
|____________
```

When number of items in Detail section are not equal then Group Header-Footer are not displayed in the same line.

How its possible to achieve it in this way:

```
-------------------------
| Receipt 1 | Receipt 2 |
|_______________________|
|  Item 1   | Item 1    |
|  Item 2   | Item 2    |
|  Item 3   |           |
-------------------------
|  Receipt1 | Receipt2  |
|  Total    | Total     |
|_______________________|
```

Comment: can you show design?

Comment: @Siva Group Header/Footer Sections are used for receipt, and Detail Section contain items.

Comment: Thats fine... But we need to see how you draw the lines and how you placed the fields in details.. which will make difference in preview.. If you are unable to show the preview then atleast explain how have you designed the report

Comment: @Siva Finally, I have added blank items in Receipt2 and suppress blank items. Same in case of Receipt1 if Receipt2 have more items.

Comment: Thats great... can you post it as answer and accept it so that any one who has the same problem can use

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to put the totals and header in different sections from that of item details. This should result in the the totals showing up aligned as expected.

Comment: Header and totals are in Group Header/Footer section. And Detail section contain only items.

Comment: That's odd. If this is different sections then this should not stagger the way you have represented. Can you attach the report design image so that we may help your further.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking help on Crystal Report and it's a design problem, please show your design better, we need to see the lines  and the details between each section to help you well.

To achieve what you want, the lines for your Group Detail section needs to be until the beginning of your Group Footer section. ( the line must begin in the GroupDetailSection and finish in the beginning of the GroupFooterSection )